# Could any one derive this identity by definition of integral

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, power-series

I know it can be proved by induction.
If you don't know one side of the equality.How to derive the other side.I just want to know how the mathematicians derive this.

> In Exercise 3.3.5, the reader is asked to prove that
> $$\int_{\lambda w}^\infty\frac{z^{k-1}e^{-z}}{(k-1)!}\,dz=\sum_{x=0}^{k-1}\frac{(\lambda w)^xe^{-\lambda w}}{x!}.$$

Comment: or any other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identity:

$$\int_{\lambda w}^\infty \frac{z^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\ e^{-z}\ \text{d} z = \sum_{x = 0}^{k - 1} \frac{(\lambda w)^x}{x!}\ e^{-\lambda w}$$

can be proved using integration by parts. In fact:

$$I_{k-1} := \int_{\lambda w}^\infty \frac{z^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\ e^{-z}\ \text{d} z = \left. \frac{z^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\ e^{-z} \right|_{\lambda w}^\infty + \int_{\lambda w}^\infty \frac{z^{k-2}}{(k-2)!}\ e^{-z}\ \text{d} z = \frac{(\lambda w)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\ e^{-\lambda w} + I_{k-2}$$

therefore:

$$I_{k-1} = \sum_{x = 1}^{k - 1} \frac{(\lambda w)^x}{x!}\ e^{-\lambda w} + I_0 = \sum_{x = 1}^{k - 1} \frac{(\lambda w)^x}{x!}\ e^{-\lambda w} + \int_{\lambda w}^\infty e^{-z}\ \text{d} z = \sum_{x = 0}^{k - 1} \frac{(\lambda w)^x}{x!}\ e^{-\lambda w}\; .$$

Answer (score 0):

This can be proven using basic facts about Poisson processes. Let $X_{i}$ be i.i.d. exponential random variables with mean $1/\lambda$ for $i\geq 1$ and put $T_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Here $X_i$ are the inter-arrival times and put $T_n$ is the time of the $n$th arrival. Then put $N_{t}=\sup \{n\mid T_{n}\leq t\}$ be the number of arrivals by time $t$. One can readily compute that $T_{n}$ is gamma distributed with shape parameter $n$ and scale $\lambda^{-1}$ while $N_{t}$ is Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda t$. Now we observe the key identity
$$
T_{k}>t\iff N_{t}<k
$$
i.e. the $k$ th arrival happens after time $t$ iff the number of arrivals by time $t$ is less than $k$. Then your identity is simply the consequence that
$$
P(T_k>w)=P(N_{w}<k).
$$

Comment: emmm... Sorry,this question before the author claimed that it is gamma distribution. In fact it is one step of the proof that it satisfies gamma distribution.